# Single instance of mpv while maintaining the coordinates of the previous window

Tags: bash

The code I am using is:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(pidof "mpv")

if [[ "$pid" ]]; then
wmctrl -x -R gl.mpv
echo "{ \"command\": [\"loadfile\", \"$1\", \"append\"] }" | socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket"
echo playlist-next | socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket"
else
    mpv --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpv-socket --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui "$1"
fi
```

It makes sure that there is only one instance of mpv. It also make sure that the new instance is open in the previous window's position. It also has memory. I mean, it adds to the playlist then play it. So, I can go to the previous video.

Please note that `socat` must be installed in the machine.

How can I make this code better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Make the important elements easy to see

In the posted code I mean the script parameter `$1`.
Currently it appears in the middle of the code in two places.
Until I take a closer look, I don't even know the script takes a parameter.

I suggest to store the script parameters early in the script in a variable.
And make sure the variable has a descriptive name,
it's crucial to help readers understand the meaning and purpose.
In this example it seems the parameter is a path to a file,
so I suggest to do this near the top of the script:

```
path=$1
```

`gl.mpv` might be a good candidate too, to give a descriptive name near the top of the script.

#### Validate parameters

In both branches of the if-statement, the parameter is used.
Therefore it seems it's a required parameter for the script to work well.
Here's one way to validate this and exit when the parameter is missing:

```
if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Missing parameter: path-to-file"
    echo >&2 "usage: $0 path-to-file"
    exit 1
fi
```

And if the parameter must be a path to a file,
it probably makes sense to also verify that:

```
if ! [[ -f $1 ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Not a file: $1"
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Let Bash raise errors on suspicious operations

I start all my Bash scripts with this, to mitigate the impact of certain mistakes:

```
set -euo pipefail
```

This does a bunch of helpful things:

- `-e` makes the script abort on the first failing command, which can help in many ways

  - avoid disasters by failing fast
  - highlight that something unexpected happened
  - make the failure easy to see, at the end of the script output
  - encourages implementing solid error handling
- `-u` makes it an error when referencing an undefined variable; together with `-e`, this again can help avoid disasters
- `-o pipefail` makes the exit code of a pipeline success only when all commands exit with success (you can read more about it in `man bash`, search for "pipefail")

#### Don't repeat yourself

`socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket"` appears twice in the script.
You can avoid duplicated logic using a function:

```
socat_to_mpv() {
    socat - "/tmp/mpv-socket"
}
```

And then use `... | socat_to_mpv` in the pipelines.

#### Improve readability using single quotes

This expression is a bit hard to read because of all the escaping of embedded double-quotes:

> ```
> echo "{ \"command\": [\"loadfile\", \"$1\", \"append\"] }"
> ```

In situations like this you could use single quotes instead, but *carefully*:

```
echo '{ "command": ["loadfile", "'"$1"'", "append"] }'
```

Notice what's happening around the `$1` there. The basic pattern here is this:

```
echo '...'"$1"'...'
```

That is, when you want to embed a variable in a single-quoted string,
"interrupt" the single-quoted string with a `'`,
double-quote the variable as recommended for safety,
and then start again the single-quoted string for the remaining part.

#### Indent the body of if-else statements

In the posted code the if-branch is not indented,
which makes it a bit harder to read.
That is, instead of this:

> ```
> if [[ "$pid" ]]; then
> ...
> else
>     ...
> fi
> ```

Better to write like this:

```
if [[ "$pid" ]]; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```